# loop throw 2 dimensional array and print out most common char in each place Python

Tags: python, multidimensional-array

I have a two dimensional array 5x10 size like this:

```
[[ '0', 'A', 'M', 'P', '0', '0', 'a', '0', '0', '0'],
 [ '0', 'H', '0', 'Q', '0', '0', 't', '0', '0', '0'],
 [ 'q', 'C', 'M', 'P', 'r', '0', '0', '0', 'w', 'i'],
 [ '0', 'H', '0', 'P', '0', 't', 'h', '0', '0', '0'],
 [ '0', 'C', 'M', 'Q', 'r', '0', '0', '0', 'r', 'p']]
```

I want to loop throu this array in a way that I loop through columns instead of lines. I check the most common **char** (not numbers) and I then print out the most common character out. If there are equally common character in the column then randomly pick one of the most common ones. Example:

First column there are only 1 char "q" so this is easy. In second column there are 2 common chars "C" and "H" so just choose one of them randomly and so on through all the columns.

Can someone help me out with that. I do not really know how to do. Thanks!

**EDIT**

I can now iterate through the columns and print out the values in each column. What is left is to print out the most common one.

```
for i in range(0, 10):
  for row in arr:
    print(row[i])
```

Example Output for first column:

```
0
0
q
0
0
```

Comment: Zip your rows together. Say that array is `x`, then to iterate over the columns simply do `zip(*x)`.

Comment: @blorgon I have never used zip function so let me read about it just a sec. However I just edited my question. I can iterate through my columns and print out but I want to print or "save" the most common one of them. Can you please check it out

Comment: @blorgon I am trying to find an awnser at same time as I posted my question. It does not mean that I just lay down and wait for awnsers to pour down on me and I choose the best one. It is just that I am not so familiar with python and I need little help. I am still trying to find an awnser without you pointing it out. Thanks for your help!

Comment: This website is for posting questions like "here's some code that isn't working, can I get help?" It is off-topic on this site to ask "how do I do this?". You have to show what you've tried so far. Some people have since answered, so consider yourself lucky. In the future, don't expect posts like this to stay open for long.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `random.choice` and `statistics.multimode`:

```
>>> from random import choice
>>> from statistics import multimode
>>> table = [
        [ '0', 'A', 'M', 'P', '0', '0', 'a', '0', '0', '0'],
        [ '0', 'H', '0', 'Q', '0', '0', 't', '0', '0', '0'],
        [ 'q', 'C', 'M', 'P', 'r', '0', '0', '0', 'w', 'i'],
        [ '0', 'H', '0', 'P', '0', 't', 'h', '0', '0', '0'],
        [ '0', 'C', 'M', 'Q', 'r', '0', '0', '0', 'r', 'p']
    ]

>>> for column in zip(*table):
        alphas = [char for char in column if char.isalpha()]
        if alphas: 
            print(choice(multimode(alphas)))
        else:
            print(None)

q
C
M
P
r
t
t
None
r
p
```

In `python 3.8+` it is possible to use a generator comprehension with walrus operator:

```
>>> print(*[
        choice(multimode(alphas)) 
        if (alphas:= list(filter(str.isalpha, column))) else None 
        for column in zip(*table)
    ], sep='\n')

q
H
M
P
r
t
h
None
w
i
```